# joining two tables with a condition

Tags: sql

I will explain my question by example

I have two tables:

1- Scales(id, name, min_grade, max_grade, college_id)

2- college(id, name)

I want to search into the two tables and get all records when scales.name = "name" and college.name="name" (same name) with the following condition 
college.id must be exist in the first table(Scales.college_id) to get the record from second one.

What is proper query to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this makes no sense - surely `Scales.CollegeID` and `College.ID` would be the columns that match, not the names?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `JOIN`:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

```
SELECT *
FROM scales
INNER JOIN college
ON scales.college_id = college.id
WHERE scales.name = "SomeName"
```

Comment: I think the field in `scales` was specified as `college_id` - but yep, that'd get it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple inner join will do it:

```
select scales.id, scales.name, scales.min_grade, scales.max_grade, scales.college_id
from scales
inner join college
on scales.college_id = college.id
```